# ArrayList Index out of bounds but actually not?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I am having a very confusing bug with my java code right now. I am just going to insert the important parts of my code, and explain what it should do:

```
 ArrayList<String> superstarKandidaten = new ArrayList<>(freundesliste.keySet()); //there are exactly 5 keys in freundesliste, and after checking the content of superstarKandidaten, it gives me 5 different values (everything how I wanted it to be)
```

Now, the following code looks a bit weird, its basically supposed to read two values of superstarKandidaten which aren't the same.

```
int i = 0;    
while (superstarKandidaten.size() > 1) {
                if (i + 1 > superstarKandidaten.size()) i = 0; else i++;
                System.out.println(i);
                person1 = superstarKandidaten.get(i);
                System.out.println(person1);
                if (i + 1 > superstarKandidaten.size()) i = 0; else i++;
                System.out.println(i);
                person2 = superstarKandidaten.get(i); // <-- this is where the error happens according to the error message. (this is Ausrechnen.java:24
                System.out.println(person2);
                if (person1.equals(person2)) {
                    if (i + 1 > superstarKandidaten.size()) {
                        i = 0;
                    }else i++;
                    person2 = superstarKandidaten.get(i);
                }
```

I am not going to write the rest of the code since it is unnecesarry, here is the output:

```
    {Knuth=null Turing Dijkstra, Hoare=null Turing Dijkstra Codd, Turing=Hoare Dijkstra, Codd=null Turing Dijkstra Knuth, Dijkstra=null} // this is freundesliste
[Knuth, Hoare, Turing, Codd, Dijkstra] //this is superstarKandidaten
1 //this is i
Hoare //this is person1
2 //this is i
Turing //this is person2
3
Dijkstra
4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
    at Ausrechnen.superstar(Ausrechnen.java:24)
    at Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Comment: Are you sure the size of the ArrayList is 5?

Comment: The condition `superstarKandidaten.size() > 1` implies you are removing items from `superstarKandidaten`. Do you?

Comment: Yes, is that a problem? I thought it would update every time something happens to the array list and calculates the size new since I am using while...

Comment: @FABULATOR there are some expectations about code snippets: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the actual size of your list is, this snippet contains a flaw:

> ```
> if (i + 1 > superstarKandidaten.size()) i = 0; else i++;
> System.out.println(i);
> person2 = superstarKandidaten.get(i);
> ```

The `if` allows `i` to reach `super....size()`, while valid indices are in the range of `0`...`super...size()-1`.

e.g. `i=3`, `super...size()=4`, `3+1>4?` No, `i=4`. Then `super...get(4)` dies.

Comment: Btw, the same problem applies to the identical code snippet with `person1`. I was just looking at the line you pointed at.